# iOS NavigationController hide the navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

ViewController A push to ViewController B.

And ViewController A :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

But I don't want to hide the navigationbar in ViewController B,

and in ViewController B :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

But this do not work, how can I show the navigationbar in B?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put some code how you initialize & push view controller B.

Comment: @Rahul I use storyboard : [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toViewB" sender:self];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//ViewControllerB.m

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    }
```

//ViewControllerA.m

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    }
```

Remember Editor->Embed IN -> NavigationController for RootViewController in StoryBoard or init NavigationController in AppDelegate if use XIB